# Stroke randomization changing after initialization

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I have a number of line shapes in After Effects. I want their stroke to initialize to a random width at the start of the animation and that width not to change for the entire animation.

The initialization does indeed work, but when I advance to the next frame, the stroke width is set to 0.1, then on the next frame 0.2, etc. I can't understand what might cause this.

```
now = time;
if (now == 0) content("Shape 1").content("Stroke 1").strokeWidth = random() * 10 + 2;
```

There will be many lines. It's not practical to hand-assign widths. How can I achieve my goal of setting a random stroke width at the start of animation and having it not change?

Comment: There seems to be some trouble with your `random` function. Would you post it?

Comment: Random is provided by the After Effects environment. It's documented to produce a random floating point number in the range 0..1.